# Use of CICD tools for project production

Tags: git, jenkins, docker, sonarqube

I want to implement concept of CI and CD with my project, I want to use Jenkins, SonarQube and docker together for it, now I have confusion that, how I can able to design system architect of my project with these tools. what will be the flow of my project development to deployment?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

It's a broad question, but fundamentally what you'll do is put together a build pipeline in Jenkins, which is triggered when a developer pushes changes to source control. The pipeline would do something like this:

- build the project, run unit tests & SonarQube analysis
- build a Docker image which packages up the application & its dependencies
- run a Docker container from the image & run integration tests
- run/upgrade Docker container in the QA environment and run smoke tests
- run/upgrade Docker container in production

There are many variations, but the core idea is that there are several stages, each with its own quality gate, and all automated. E.g. if unit tests fail the pipeline fails and you don't build the image; if integration tests fail you don't deploy to the QA environment etc.

The advantage of using Docker is that each stage uses exactly the same application stack, because its bundled in the image. What you deploy in prod is what you've approved from QA, which is what passed your integration tests.

You can have a manual quality gate before the production release, for humans to check the app. That's not fully automated CD, but it can make people more comfortable.

Comment: Also, [this free eBook from Codeship](https://resources.codeship.com/ebooks/continuous-integration-continuous-delivery-with-docker) is a good introduction to the whole area.